# Querying multiple select query

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

As of now, I am iterating through a pandas dataframe one by one and firing a select query to check whether the data is present or not, to the database based on few dataframe values.

```
 for index, frame in dataframe.iterrows():
     # select query based on multiple frame['column_1'],frame['column_2']
```

It would take forever if the data is huge. I was just curious, is there a way where I can fire all the select at once and filter out my dataframe for which I get a result back.?

Comment: Can you bring the data in the database into memory? If so, you could do that and then use a join or anti-join to find if any rows present or missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ["A", "B", "C"]

data = [
    [1,2,3],
    [1,1,1],
    [3,5,4],
    [2,5,3]
]

my_pandas = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

# Create a filter on the dataframe
my_pandas[my_pandas["A"] == 1]

# Create 2 filters (Don't forget the parenthesis. It's important)
my_pandas[(my_pandas["A"] == 1) & (my_pandas["C"] == 3)]
```

Result

```
    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
```

Comment: I could create a dataframe filtering out the columns I need for my select query. The question was, is there a way , I can fire multiple select queries at once to avoid my loop iterations.

Comment: Could you post an exemple ? I don't see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post helps you:
[how to transform pandas dataframe for insertion via executemany() statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938613/how-to-transform-pandas-dataframe-for-insertion-via-executemany-statement)

MySQL, for example, has a `executemany()` that does pretty much exactly what I understand you want. Perhaps there is something like that using Pandas and numpy.. I haven't worked with those two yet

Comment: I am afraid not.