# MySQL: How do I write query to choose MAX and today date to fetch data from given list and store in DB

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I having problem regarding store data in mysql database. a variable having list of list `df = [['Euro', 0.877641, '2018-10-24'], ['British Pound', 0.7752180000000001, '2018-10-24'], ['Indian Rupee', 73.21869000000001, '2018-10-24'], ['Australian Dollar', 1.4135360000000001, '2018-10-24'], ['Canadian Dollar', 1.299316, '2018-10-24']]` want to store this in the column currency_name, date ,value from the last updated date. So How could i write that logic in code(my be with max(), min() method of sql.)

tryied:

```
    import pandas as pd
     import pymysql
    import MySQLdb
        sqlconn = pymysql.connect(host='ip', port=port, user='username',
                                  passwd='pass', db='dbname', autocommit=True)
        # Create a cursor object
        if (sqlconn == None):
            print("conn not found")
        else:
            print("conn is found")


        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TestCurrencyHistory (currency, date, value) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)") % (
                                              elements
                                            )
        element = cursor.fetchall()

        cursor.close()
        sqlconn.close()
Offcource this is not working. So please help ..
```

thanks in advance..(please let me no if there is any python/pandas logic to choose max and min date)

Comment: Hello. Could you precise your issue with input / output data required ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mysql-connector, you could use [`executemany()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) but I'm not sure if pandas supports that yet. This post could help: [how to transform pandas dataframe for insertion via executemany() statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938613/how-to-transform-pandas-dataframe-for-insertion-via-executemany-statement)

```
df = [['Euro', 0.877641, '2018-10-24'], ['British Pound', 0.7752180000000001, '2018-10-24'], ['Indian Rupee', 73.21869000000001, '2018-10-24'], ['Australian Dollar', 1.4135360000000001, '2018-10-24'], ['Canadian Dollar', 1.299316, '2018-10-24']]
```

To get the latest date of `df`:

```
date_list = []
for x in df:
    date_list.append(x[-1])
latest = max(date_list)

# turn into datetime format, not str
latest = datetime.datetime.strptime(latest, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

# increase by one day
next_day = latest + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

I don't know what your SQL query looks like, but you might then do something like the following to get data from the next day:

```
latest_date_query_results = cursor.execute(
"""
SELECT currency, value, added_date
FROM your_table
WHERE added_date > {}
""".format(next_day)
)
```

The results should be turned into a tuple to work with `executemany()`

```
elements = [] 
for x in df:
    elements.append(tuple((x)))
elements = tuple((elements))
print(elements)
# (('Euro', 0.877641, '2018-10-24'), ('British Pound', 0.7752180000000001, '2018-10-24'), ('Indian Rupee', 73.21869000000001, '2018-10-24'), ('Australian Dollar', 1.4135360000000001, '2018-10-24'), ('Canadian Dollar', 1.299316, '2018-10-24'))
```

Then, you could do this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO TestCurrencyHistory (currency, date, value) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
cursor.executemany(sql, elements)
```

Comment: To get help on the max() piece, I'll need a little more info about what exactly you're trying to do. Do you want to only insert data for the latest date?

Comment: I convert that data like:                                                                                                          RIC       price       Added
0                   Euro,    0.877641,  2018-10-24
1          British Pound,    0.775218,  2018-10-24
2           Indian Rupee,   73.218690,  2018-10-24
3      Australian Dollar,    1.413536 , 2018-10-24 ...........................I want to find last updated date from the previous there, from next to that date want to add the above data

Comment: Sorry, not super sure what exactly you're trying to do. This article shows you how to get the latest date in SQL:
https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/max-date.php

Comment: Got Max date, want to add data from next to that date Suppose max date is 2018-10-20 so want to add data in existing table from 2018-10-21(may be with python, sql, pandas)

Comment: added to the answer, hope this helps!

Comment: with your answer this error will comming:   ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Seems to be a pandas-specific error that has to do with "and / or" statements in python: https://markhneedham.com/blog/2017/07/26/pandas-valueerror-the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous/

Perhaps this link helps you resolve. It's a separate issue, though!

Comment: @pavan have you been able to resolve? Would be helpful if you accepted as answer if so :)