# Python DataFrame to MYSQL: TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

Been playing with this for 14 hours (I am a beginner)

Data is pulled from one database table to search on yahoo for all the data on that ticker and then its "meant" to upload it.

I orginally had it as panda df but got "ambiguous error" so I have now put it as [] again. New error. I rack my brains :( However, it does work if I leave it blank.

```
    from __future__ import print_function
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import warnings
import MySQLdb as mdb
import requests
import numpy as np
import MySQLdb as mdb
import requests


# Obtain a database connection to the MySQL instance
con = mdb.connect("localhost","sec_user","","securities_master")


def obtain_list_of_db_tickers():
    """
    Obtains a list of the ticker symbols in the database.
    """
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT id, ticker FROM symbol")
        data = cur.fetchall()
        print(data)
        return [(d[0], d[1]) for d in data]

def get_daily_historic_data_yahoo(ticker):
    blow = yf.download(ticker)
    data = []
    data.append(yf.download(ticker).reset_index())
    return data

def insert_daily_data_into_db(data_vendor_id, symbol_id, daily_data):
    '''
    Takes a list of tuples of daily data and adds it to the MySQL database.
    Appends the vendor ID and symbol ID to the data.

    daily_data: List of tuples of the OHLC data (with adj_close and volume)
    '''

    # Create the time now
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=daily_data[0])
    df.insert(0, 'data_vendor_id', data_vendor_id)
    df.insert(1, 'symbol_id', symbol_id)
    df.insert(3, 'created_date', now)
    df.insert(4, 'last_updated_date', now)
    daily_data = []
    daily_data.append(df)

    #df = daily_data

       # Amend the data to include the vendor ID and symbol ID


    # Connect to the MySQL instance
    db_host = 'localhost'
    db_user = ''
    db_pass = ''
    db_name = 'securities_master'
    con = mdb.connect("localhost", "sec_user", "", "securities_master"
                      # host=db_host, user=db_user, passwd=db_pass, db=db_name
                      )

    try:
        mdb.connect
    # If connection is not successful
    except:
        print("Can't connect to database")
        return 0

    # If Connection Is Successful
    print("Connected")


    final_str = """INSERT INTO daily_price (data_vendor_id, symbol_id, price_date, created_date,
    last_updated_date, open_price, high_price, low_price, close_price, volume, adj_close_price) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""

    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.executemany(final_str, daily_data)
        con.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This ignores the warnings regarding Data Truncation
    # from the Yahoo precision to Decimal(19,4) datatypes
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

    # Loop over the tickers and insert the daily historical
    # data into the database
    tickers = obtain_list_of_db_tickers()
    lentickers = len(tickers)
    for i, t in enumerate(tickers):
        print(
            "Adding data for %s: %s out of %s" %
            (t[1], i+1, lentickers)
        )
        yf_data = get_daily_historic_data_yahoo(t[1])
        insert_daily_data_into_db('1', t[0], yf_data)
    print("Successfully added Yahoo Finance pricing data to DB.")
```

Errors

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/quant/price_retrieval.py", line 106, in <module>
    insert_daily_data_into_db('1', t[0], yf_data)
  File "/home/quant/price_retrieval.py", line 88, in insert_daily_data_into_db

        cur.executemany(final_str, daily_data)
      File "/home/quant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 230, in executemany
        return self._do_execute_many(
      File "/home/quant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 255, in _do_execute_many
        v = values % escape(next(args), conn)
    TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: Correct @snakecharmerb. I did have a fancy solution but ended up with simplicity and manullay coding the %s 

I can confirm that print(datadaily) comes up with 11 columns, I even tried adding a column to see if that works.

Comment: so if I use: print(len(df.columns)) to check. There are 11. If I print(dailydata) there are 11. 

If I use Daily Data in the executive many, the error is: TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: If I use df the error is: ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: writing to CSV is interesting thou. there is no header on the first column:

,data_vendor_id,symbol_id,Date,created_date,last_updated_date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
0,1,5051,1970-01-02,2021-12-17 08:29:17.962685,2021-12-17 08:29:17.962685,6.851562976837158,6.890625,6.84375,6.851562976837158,1.4377198219299316,72000

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938613/how-to-transform-pandas-dataframe-for-insertion-via-executemany-statement

Comment: Yes I believe it looks like a similar problem AustEcon placed it into a row statement and it worked a charm, obviously needed to be spelled out to the database :( thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no data scientist so there's probably a more elegant way to fix it directly with pandas. But the way I usually work with MySQL (and really any SQL drivers) is to give it lists of python tuples.

If you parse each row of the pandas data frame with `for row in df.itertuples():` and craft each tuple carefully - making sure the types match the SQL table, all should work ;)

Example:

```
def insert_daily_data_into_db(data_vendor_id, symbol_id, daily_data):
    '''
    Takes a list of tuples of daily data and adds it to the MySQL database.
    Appends the vendor ID and symbol ID to the data.

    daily_data: List of tuples of the OHLC data (with adj_close and volume)
    '''

    # Create the time now
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=daily_data[0])
    daily_data = []
    created_date = now
    last_updated_date = now
    for row in df.itertuples():
        _index = row[0]  # discard
        date = row[1]
        open = row[2]
        high = row[3]
        low = row[4]
        close = row[5]
        adj_close_price = row[6]
        volume = row[7]
        daily_data.append((int(data_vendor_id), symbol_id, date, created_date, last_updated_date, open, high, low, close, volume, adj_close_price))

    # Connect to the MySQL instance
    con = mdb.connect(host="localhost", user="user", password="yourpassword",
        db="yourdbname", port=3306)

    final_str = """
        INSERT INTO daily_price (data_vendor_id, symbol_id, price_date, created_date,
        last_updated_date, open_price, high_price, low_price, close_price, volume, adj_close_price) 
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
    """

    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.executemany(final_str, daily_data)
        con.commit()
```

I've tried not to tamper with your existing code too much. Just enough to make it work.

I think what was happening there for you was that you're technically passing it a list of pandas dataframes with only a single pandas dataframe in the list. Instead what you want is a list of tuples with 11 fields to unpack per tuple.

Maybe you mean to pass the dataframe directly i.e. not contained inside of a list but I still don't think that would be right because 1) there's an "Index" column in the dataframe which would give erroneous results 2) you'd need to call some methods on the dataframe to retrieve only the values (not the headers to the columns) and transform it to the correct list of tuples. It's probably very doable but I will leave that to you to find out.

I am also assuming your table schema is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS daily_price (
    data_vendor_id INT,
    symbol_id INT,
    price_date DATETIME,
    created_date DATETIME,
    last_updated_date TIMESTAMP,
    open_price VARCHAR(256),
    high_price VARCHAR(256),
    low_price VARCHAR(256),
    close_price VARCHAR(256),
    volume INT,
    adj_close_price VARCHAR(256)
);
```

Comment: I admit, I thought, noooooooooo this can't be it. However, it works haha, why for row? I was trying to edit columns. Yes the index was causing issues with passing directly and indirectly tbh, this works nicely :) I have 4 million new records

Comment: thanks for your help :)

Comment: Glad you got it working. Why for rows? I'm not sure I understand the question. I'm not suggesting the above code is the perfect solution by any stretch but to me it's the most simple, intuitive thing to do: iterate over all the rows of the pandas data frame and craft each tuple to be exactly how you need it... Of course there's no reason to put it into the pandas dataframe to begin with. It's entirely redundant here...